# How to identify confounding variables in a design matrix?

Tags: regression, experiment-design

Consider for example the following design matrix with columns $[0...k]$:

```
[[1,  ,  ,  ,  ],
 [1,  ,  ,  , 1],
 [1, 1,  ,  ,  ],
 [1, 1,  ,  , 1],
 [1,  , 1,  ,  ],
 [1,  , 1,  , 1],
 [1,  ,  , 1,  ],
 [1,  ,  , 1, 1]]

 (spaces are zeroes)
```

How do I check if a design matrix is confounded?

I thought I'd check if the column sum of unique rows in the design matrix equals to '1' in each slope column:

${\sum_{1..k}}$ = [2, 2, 2, 4]
=> confounded, since $\exists$ value $\neq$ 1

However, is this a general solution?
What if I'd get some design matrix with (-1, 1) instead of (0, 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I found the solution:

The matrix is confounded, since it overdetermines the model.
E.g., $D_2 = D_4 - D_3 + D_1$.
This is the case, if the column count is higher than the row rank.

In other words, the matrix rank is equal to the number of columns in non-confounded design matrices.

Comment: Well, not really. Row rank and column rank are always equal. But maybe you are meaning something else with 'rank', ? maybe number of rows/columns?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right, thank you!
I've re-written my answer, I hope I got it right now ^^